# How to convert a list into a Pandas Dataframe ? pd.DataFrame does not work on this list structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data :

Sample data:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Candidate_id': pd.Series([533334, 533334, 533334, 533334, 533334],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)), 'SkillMatch': pd.Series([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],dtype='float64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)), 'Hired_User_id': pd.Series([533441, 634908, 635261, 635309, 635575],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1))`
```

I make the following transformations to get my required data, which returns a list

```
for i in d['Candidate_id'].unique():
    rand_candidates.append(d[d['Candidate_id'] == i].sample(n = 1, random_state=7))      `
```

And, I want to convert the data in list `rand_candidates` to a `DataFrame`

I tried

```
pd.DataFrame(data=rand_candidates, columns = ["Candidate_id", "SkillMatch", "Hired_User_id"])
```

but it gives a KeyError and I don't understand why.

`rand_sample[0]` returns a single row of the dataframe that I need but since it's from a list I cannot further manipulate that, so it's of no use:
[Slice of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVWeh.png)

Comment: I think you should put square brackets around rand_candidates when converting it to a dataframe.

Comment: Tried that, got ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 100 columns. And 100 is the length of list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in your `list` is dataframe , that is why dataframe constructor dose not work, we should use `concat`

```
yourdf=pd.concat(rand_candidates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why convert to a list, you can do:

```
d[d['Candidate_id'] == i].sample(n = 1, random_state=7)

and

d[d['Candidate_id'] == i].sample(n = 1, random_state=7).to_csv()
```

to get the dataframe your looking for and a format that you can read it back in. I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that, definitely helps